# Remove trailing comma from STUFF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with addresses and only want to show countries if they're not in the UK. This works but I am left with a trailing comma on only the UK addresses and am not sure how to remove it. I'm guessing my `STUFF` is not the correct syntax or I need to do this differently?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2cb48/5

Example data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AddressDetails]
(
    [AddressID] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [PropertyNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PropertyName] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Street] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Locality] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Town] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [PostCode] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [County] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
)

INSERT INTO AddressDetails(PropertyNumber, PropertyName, Street, Locality, Town, PostCode, County, Country)
VALUES     
    ('1', NULL, 'Main Street', 'Ilford', 'London', 'E1 1JA', 'Londonshire', 'United Kingdom'),
    ('135', NULL, 'Apple Avenue', NULL, 'Reading', 'RG15 2FC', 'Berkshire', 'GB'),
    ('115/A', 'Cool Building', 'Siskin Close', 'Bushey', 'Watford', 'WD23 2HN', 'Greater London', 'GB'),
    ('1600', 'Amphitheatre', NULL, 'Parkway', 'Mountain View', '94043', 'California', 'USA'),
    ('7221', NULL, 'Shore Lane', 'Hempstead', 'NY', '11550', NULL, 'America!')
```

Query:

```
SELECT STUFF(                                           
    COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([PropertyName],''),'')
    +COALESCE(', '+NULLIF(PropertyNumber,''),'')
    +COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([Street],''),'')
    +COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([Locality],''),'')
    +COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([Town],''),'')                                            
    +COALESCE(', '+UPPER(NULLIF([Postcode],'')),'') 
    +COALESCE(', '+ CASE WHEN UPPER([Country]) IN ('GB', 'UNITED KINGDOM') THEN '' ELSE UPPER(NULLIF([Country],'')) END,'')                                                             
    ,1,2,'') as [FullAddress]
FROM AddressDetails
```

Output:

```
1, Main Street, Ilford, London, E1 1JA,
135, Apple Avenue, Reading, RG15 2FC,
Cool Building, 115/A, Siskin Close, Bushey, Watford, WD23 2HN,
Amphitheatre, 1600, Parkway, Mountain View, 94043, USA
7221, Shore Lane, Hempstead, NY, 11550, AMERICA!
```

Desired output:

```
1, Main Street, Ilford, London, E1 1JA
135, Apple Avenue, Reading, RG15 2FC
Cool Building, 115/A, Siskin Close, Bushey, Watford, WD23 2HN
Amphitheatre, 1600, Parkway, Mountain View, 94043, USA
7221, Shore Lane, Hempstead, NY, 11550, AMERICA!
```

Comment: Note, `STUFF` doesn't remove the trailing comma, it removes the leading comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with your STUFF, its your Country line. Do this and note the position of the **', ' +** .

```
SELECT STUFF(                                           
COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([PropertyName],''),'')
+COALESCE(', '+NULLIF(PropertyNumber,''),'')
+COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([Street],''),'')
+COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([Locality],''),'')
+COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([Town],''),'')                                            
+COALESCE(', '+UPPER(NULLIF([Postcode],'')),'') 
+COALESCE(CASE WHEN UPPER([Country]) IN ('GB', 'UNITED KINGDOM') THEN '' ELSE ', ' + UPPER(NULLIF([Country],'')) END,'')                                                             
,1,2,'') as [FullAddress]
FROM AddressDetails
```

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 3):

```
    Select right(rtrim(FullAddress),1) = ',' then substring(rtrim(FullAddress),1,len(rtrim(FullAddress))-1) as [FullAddress]  From 
(SELECT STUFF(                                           
    COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([PropertyName],''),'')
    +COALESCE(', '+NULLIF(PropertyNumber,''),'')
    +COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([Street],''),'')
    +COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([Locality],''),'')
    +COALESCE(', '+NULLIF([Town],''),'')                                            
    +COALESCE(', '+UPPER(NULLIF([Postcode],'')),'') 
    +COALESCE(', '+ CASE WHEN UPPER([Country]) IN ('GB', 'UNITED KINGDOM') THEN '' ELSE UPPER(NULLIF([Country],'')) END,'')                                                             
    ,1,2,'') as [FullAddress]
FROM AddressDetails) temp
```

please check, this can help you

Answer (score 2):

Late answer

Just wanted to point out that `CONCAT()` will handle `NULL` values as an empty string.

Personally, I find it a bit easier to read.

**Example**

```
SELECT  stuff(
        concat(
              ', '+NullIf([PropertyName]  ,'')
             ,', '+NULLIF([PropertyNumber],'')
             ,', '+NULLIF([Street]        ,'')
             ,', '+NULLIF([Locality]      ,'')
             ,', '+NULLIF([Town]          ,'')
             ,', '+NULLIF([Postcode]      ,'')
             ,', '+NULLIF(CASE WHEN UPPER([Country]) IN ('GB', 'UNITED KINGDOM') THEN '' ELSE UPPER(NULLIF([Country],'')) END,'')
             )
         ,1,2,'')
FROM AddressDetails
```

**Returns**

```
(No column name)
1, Main Street, Ilford, London, E1 1JA
135, Apple Avenue, Reading, RG15 2FC
Cool Building, 115/A, Siskin Close, Bushey, Watford, WD23 2HN
Amphitheatre, 1600, Parkway, Mountain View, 94043, USA
7221, Shore Lane, Hempstead, NY, 11550, AMERICA!
```